# How to get the correct value and type of NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I am creating an `NSNumber` from string by check if the string is `float` or `int` using `NSNumberFormatter`. I want to have a method to return what type the `NSNumber` holds and the correct value. It works for `int`, but not working for decimal numbers.

```c
NSNumber *n;
enum CFNumberType _numberType;

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        decimalPattern = @"\\d+(\\.\\d+)";
        if ([Utils matchString:string withPattern:decimalPattern]) {
            // Float
            formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
            _numberType = kCFNumberDoubleType;
            n = [formatter numberFromString:string];
        } else {
            // Integer
            formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
            _numberType = kCFNumberIntType;
            n = [formatter numberFromString:string];
        }
        self = [self initWithNumber:n];
    }
    return self;
}


- (CFNumberType)value {
    CFNumberType num;  // How to determine the type of num? 
    CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)n, _numberType, &num);
    return num;
}

- (CFNumberType)numberType {
    return _numberType;
}
```

In the `value` method, if I specify `float num`, then it works for floating point. But I cannot use float because I want to make it work for int as well. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. First check if the number is `double` and call the appropriate value method.

```
- (BOOL)isDouble {
    if (_numberType == kCFNumberFloatType || _numberType == kCFNumberFloat32Type || _numberType == kCFNumberFloat64Type || _numberType == kCFNumberDoubleType) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (double)doubleValue {
    if ([self isDouble]) {
        return [n doubleValue];
    }
    return 0.0;
}

- (int)intValue {
    if (![self isDouble]) {
        return [n intValue];
    }
    return 0;
}
```